# E TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable when calling a fixture

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

there is a fixture in the conftest.py file:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def get_request(url=base_url, headers=None, params=None):
     if headers is None:
         headers = {}
     elif params is None:
         params = {}
     session = requests.Session()
     response = session.get(url=url,
                            headers=get_token(), 
                            params=params,
                            verify=False,
                            )
     return response
```

which is used by the test function in the test.py file:

```
import pytest
import requests

def test_get_request2(get_request):
     response = get_request(test_url + '/endpoint')
```

when calling the function, an error occurs:

```
test_.py:17: in test_get_request2
     return get_request(test_url + '/endpoint')
E TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable
```

What is the problem?

I expect that the result of the execution of the fixture will be pulled into the test function (response to receive the request).

Comment: Why is `get_request` passed as argument to `test_get_request2`? What is actually passed in?

Comment: Why is the code that the error message mentions different from the code you have shown here?

Comment: try with `response = get_request(url=test_url + '/endpoint')`

Comment: @mkrieger1, because it is a fixture, it is passed as a parameter to the test function

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA, same error

Answer (score 0):

What you expect is exactly what is happening. The fixture is executed and the result (a Response object) is passed to the test as an argument.

The problem is in your test:

```
def test_get_request2(get_request):
     response = get_request(test_url + '/endpoint')
```

Here **get_request** is a response object, returned by the fixture and not a function that you can call.

Now I'm not completely sure what your intentions were, but if you are trying to verify that the response is successful you can do that by:

```
def test_get_request2(get_request):
         assert get_request.status_code == 200
```

Hope that makes it a bit more clear what is happening.